# Migrate the database from the windows server to the Linux server from different versions 11g to 19c

Tags: oracle11g, oracle19c, impdp, rman, expdp

We need to migrate the database from the windows server to the Linux server from different versions 11g to 19c.

Source:

- Oracle Product Version:11.2.0.4
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows x64 2012 R2
- Database Size:1.5TB

Target:

- Oracle Product Version:19.3.0.0
- Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4
- Database Size:1.5TB

Can you suggest recommended approach (steps) to move the data?

1. Either by export/import or RMAN? If any other alternatives. Kindly suggest.
2. Can you please estimate the time duration of export and import?
3. Can you please estimate the time duration of RMAN?
   In RMAN migration different OS Platform applicable?

Comment: Time estimates will be driven entirely by the hardware you have available.  We have no idea how fast your system can generate an export, backup a database, etc.  Presumably, you're taking backups now, presumably via RMAN, and presumably you validate those backups by restoring them occasionally so you presumably have an idea how long your system takes to generate and restore a backup.

Comment: Also, since this is not a programming question, I'd say it's better suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/